# Proguard error: package com.aki.example.network does not exist import com.aki.example.network.Networkable;

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

When I use Proguard in my project I have this error:

> error: package com.aki.example.network does not exist import
>   com.aki.example.network.Networkable;

Has anyone had this error in your code? Could anyone help me?

Comment: put some code and your gradle also

Comment: `-keep public class com.aki.example.**` in your proguard file

Comment: Please share some more info like your gradle and pro-guard file etc.

Comment: find proguard dump or proguard rules for any library you are using form their docs and apply it in your prohuard rules file as -

-keep public class com.aki.example.network.**{*;}

Answer (score 1):

in your Proguard file, try using -

```
-keep public class com.aki.example.network.**{*;}
```